# Open only one modal when button is clicked

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I created a Modal Service in Angular 7 [StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mk-angular-modal-service-ctkzhq):

**Modal**

```
export class Modal {

  protected modal: any = null;

  close() {
    this.modal.close();
  }

}
```

**ModalService**

```
import { ApplicationRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, EmbeddedViewRef, Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ModalService {

  private componentRef: any;
  private modalContainer: any;

  constructor(
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private appRef: ApplicationRef,
    private injector: Injector) { }

  private createFormModal(component: any): Element {

    this.componentRef = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component.component).create(this.injector);

    this.componentRef.instance.modal = this;

    this.appRef.attachView(this.componentRef.hostView);

    return (this.componentRef.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>).rootNodes[0] as HTMLElement;
  }

  open(component: any): void {

    const alertElement = this.createFormModal(component);

    const content = document.createElement('div');
    content.classList.add('modal');
    content.appendChild(alertElement);

    this.modalContainer = document.createElement('div');
    this.modalContainer.classList.add('modal');
    this.modalContainer.appendChild(content);

    document.body.appendChild(this.modalContainer);

  }

  close(): void {
    this.appRef.detachView(this.componentRef.hostView);
    this.modalContainer.parentNode.removeChild(this.modalContainer);
    this.componentRef.destroy();
  }

}
```

I am able to open the modal when clicking the button ...

The problem is that I am able to open more than one.

How can I make sure only one modal opens when clicking the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the service is a singleton (one instance in the whole app life), you can just hold the state of the modal in the service like this:

```
import { ApplicationRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, EmbeddedViewRef, Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ModalService {

  private componentRef: any;
  private modalContainer: any;
  private alertElement: any;

  constructor(
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private appRef: ApplicationRef,
    private injector: Injector) { }

  private createFormModal(component: any): Element {

    this.componentRef = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component.component).create(this.injector);

    this.componentRef.instance.modal = this;

    this.appRef.attachView(this.componentRef.hostView);

    return (this.componentRef.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>).rootNodes[0] as HTMLElement;
  }

  open(component: any): void {
    if(this.alertElement) return;

    this.alertElement = this.createFormModal(component);

    const content = document.createElement('div');
    content.classList.add('modal');
    content.appendChild(this.alertElement);

    this.modalContainer = document.createElement('div');
    this.modalContainer.classList.add('modal');
    this.modalContainer.appendChild(content);

    document.body.appendChild(this.modalContainer);
  }

  close(): void {
    this.appRef.detachView(this.componentRef.hostView);
    this.modalContainer.parentNode.removeChild(this.modalContainer);
    this.componentRef.destroy();
    this.alertElement = null;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this service is a singleton, you can just set a flag when opening a modal and toggle the flag off when closing it.  Then in your open function you could check that flag is true or not and if it is, don't open a second modal.